# Remove nested stdClass Object from single stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i need to remove nested stdClass Object. Now am get stdClass Object like this,

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cs_id] => 1
                [cs_service_name] => 2
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cs_id] => 2
                [cs_service_name] => 3
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cs_id] => 6
                [cs_service_name] => 3
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cs_id] => 7
                [cs_service_name] => 4
            )
    )
)
```

But i need stdClass Object like this,

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cs_id] => 1
                [cs_service_name] => 2
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cs_id] => 2
                [cs_service_name] => 3
            )
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cs_id] => 6
                [cs_service_name] => 3
            )
        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cs_id] => 7
                [cs_service_name] => 4
            )
    )
 )
```

any idea to remove nested stdClass Object. am using codeigniter3. Can please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add your model where it comes from.

Comment: its comes from model. But i need to remove this nested stdClass Object in the model only.

Comment: ^ it is better to generate correct array

Comment: You have too loop and create new array

Comment: How ? any idea to create new array

Comment: Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1320156/1960712) solution.

Comment: @MansoorH Show code, generating the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this code:

```
/* you have a $collection array with all objects */

$newCollection = array();
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    if (is_array($item) && count($item)) {
        foreach ($item as $subItem) {
            $newCollection[] = $subItem;
        }
    }
}

/* $newCollection is the new array collection */
```